# Is it possible to start host 0.0.0.0:port with nancy?

Tags: c#, ip, ip-address, nancy

I am trying to start host with IP `https://0.0.0.0:9000` with **`Nancy Host`** but am getting `System - The request is not supported` exception. Below is my code.

```
string strHostProtocol = "https";
string strHostIP = "0.0.0.0";
string strHostPort = "9000";

var url = strHostProtocol + "://" + strHostIP + ":" + strHostPort;
this.host = new NancyHost(new Uri(url));
this.host.Start();
```

It will allow me to start other IP address like `127.0.0.1:9000`, `192.168.100.10:9000` etc., but not `0.0.0.0:9000`. I've read that this is a valid IP. But my question is why this is not allowed to start? Is this IP reserved for any purpose?

**Update**

---

The sole purpose here is, I am trying to access a internal IP through a public IP provided. But Nancy even though starts internal IP with port, when request is provided through public IP, it will not recognize. Not sure whether this is achievable or not.

Comment: That's by TCP/IP design, 0.0.0.0 means "all" or "every" ipv4 address on the local machine and by that 0.0.0.0 is unroutable some sort of a meta address. Routing wise if you set 0.0.0.0 as routing destination, it means it's a routing item for every other network addresses.

Comment: @ʞaʎess.. I am trying this because I've made an IP of system as public IP and I've started local IP with 9000 port.. I can telnet this port with public IP, but I am not able to browser the same through internet. I heard that starting with `0.0.0.0` would be helpful..

Comment: You mean that you want to bind nancy to all interfaces, like each and every possible IP address that's allocated to the local box? If so you could try replacing "0.0.0.0" with a "+" that is a wildcard.

Comment: @ʞaʎess Oh,, Ok.. Let me try that..

Comment: Thinking out loud, I'm not really sure if Uri() will accept it though :\

Comment: After reading [Self Hosting Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Self-Hosting-Nancy), it looks like you have to use localhost instead of 0.0.0.0, and set `RewriteLocalhost` to `true`. (and you might need admin rights).

Comment: @ʞaʎess.. Yes.. It doesn't.. Throws **Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.** Exception.. :(

Comment: Localhost will start `127.0.0.1` @Wimmel which again is specific IP Address..

Comment: True, but according to the documentation, it will be rewritten as `http://+:9000/`.

Comment: My intention here is, I am trying to access a internal IP through a public IP provided.. But `Nancy` even though starts internal IP with port, when request is provided through public IP, it will not recognize. I don't know how I can achieve this.

Comment: If you use some kind of NAT, your host will receive requests on an internal IP, it does not even know the original request was sent to a public IP. If you don't use NAT, windows would probably block the request, at least ARP would not work. Maybe you can check with wireshark if anything is received?

Comment: @Wimmel.. As per my testing, it is possible to `RDP` and `telnet` to the host started but its not possible to access through `Nancy`. I mean Nancy has some drawbacks while trying to access through public IP..

Answer (score 9):

I figured out how:

```
HostConfiguration hostConf = new HostConfiguration();
hostConf.RewriteLocalhost = true;
var apiHost = new NancyHost(hostConf, new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));
apiHost.Start();
```